# Assistance in Solving a Second Order ODE (Convert to a First Order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

```
 I have to convert the following equation into a first order system:
```

$x'' + \sin(x) = 0$

```
  From here, I have converted the system as follows:
```

Let $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = x_1'$, thus

$x_1' = x'$

$x_2' = \sin(x_1)$

```
 Lastly, I need to solve this system. Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

That first one should be $x_1' = x_2$.  You won't find an explicit general solution of the system, though.  There are of course particular solutions
where $\sin(x) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Can I at least find a function of x that satisfies the equation?

Comment: If you consider $x_2$ as a function of $x_1$, you get the DE $\dfrac{dx_2}{dx_1} = \dfrac{\sin(x_1)}{x_2}$, which has solutions $x_2 = \pm \sqrt{C - 2 \cos(x_1)}$.  Is that what you mean?